# Persisting & loading metadata in a backbone.js collection

Tags: javascript, json, collections, backbone.js

I have a situation using backbone.js where I have a collection of models, and some additional information about the models.  For example, imagine that I'm returning a list of amounts: they have a quantity associated with each model.  Assume now that the unit for each of the amounts is always the same: say quarts. Then the json object I get back from my service might be something like:

```
{
    dataPoints: [
         {quantity: 5 },
         {quantity: 10 },
         ...
    ],
    unit : quarts
 }
```

Now backbone collections have no real mechanism for natively associating this meta-data with the collection, but it was suggested to me in this question: [Setting attributes on a collection - backbone js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930656/setting-attributes-on-a-collection-backbone-js) that I can extend the collection with a `.meta(property, [value])` style function - which is a great solution.  However, naturally it follows that we'd like to be able to cleanly retrieve this data from a json response like the one we have above.

Backbone.js gives us the `parse(response)` function, which allows us to specify where to extract the collection's list of models from in combination with the `url` attribute.  There is no way that I'm aware of, however, to make a more intelligent function without overloading `fetch()` which would remove the partial functionality that is already available.

My question is this: is there a better option than overloading `fetch()` (and trying it to call it's superclass implementation) to achieve what I want to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Personally, I would wrap the `Collection` inside another `Model`, and then override `parse`, like so:

```
var DataPointsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ /* etc etc */ });
var CollectionContainer = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        dataPoints: new DataPointsCollection(),
        unit: "quarts"
    },
    parse: function(obj) {
        // update the inner collection
        this.get("dataPoints").refresh(obj.dataPoints);

        // this mightn't be necessary
        delete obj.dataPoints;

        return obj;
    }
});
```

The `Collection.refresh()` call updates the model with new values. Passing in a custom `meta` value to the Collection as previously suggested might stop you from being able to bind to those meta values.

Comment: I know this contradicts the answer you got in the other post you linked, but Collections don't have all the properties of Models, like `parse`, to be able to override. If the Collection needs the meta data to have meaning, then might as well reflect that in the object structure that Backbone provides, instead of going 'out-of-band' with the meta-on-collection solution, IMO.

Comment: This seems very reasonable to me.  The key to this is the ability to override parse/url/fetch on the model object as well as the collection.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Collection.refresh() is now deprecated, use Collection.reset() instead.

Comment: In your example all instances of `CollectionContainer` will share the same instance of `dataPoints` which may not be always preferable. To avoid this, initialize `dataPoints` property with `new DataPointsCollection()` in `initialize` method.

Answer (score 0):

This meta data does not belong on the collection. It belongs in the name or some other descriptor of the code. Your code should declaratively know that the collection it has is only full of quartz elements. It already does since the url points to quartz elements.

```
var quartzCollection = new FooCollection();
quartzCollection.url = quartzurl;
quartzCollection.fetch();
```

If you really need to get this data why don't you just call

`_.uniq(quartzCollecion.pluck("unit"))[0];`

Comment: The unit isn't known in advance of the AJAX call.  I don't use `pluck`, because it would require that each model object in my collection stored the unit - which causes the size of the response to be larger than only associating it once as meta-data.  Also, there is significant overhead to doing an operation like that I suspect.

Comment: @idbentley I though { dataPoints: ... , unit } was the model. Which it is. It's just that dataPoints is a collection. So treat it like such as mentioned in @Stoive answer. Also the pluck operation isn't that expense. It just maps the models to units.