# Backbone Collection get property

Tags: backbone.js

Got a server returning a JSON object like so:

```
{
    'key1':'value'
    'key2':{
        'key2_0':'value'
    }
}
```

And a collection:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url:api.url//which returns the object above
});
var collection = new Collection();
collection.fetch({
    success:function(data){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Now i need to use certain properties of the collection throughout my application, but say i need `key1`, i always have to do `collection.at(0).get('key1');//returns 'value'`, because the data returned is stored within the collection, in a new Array at key 0.

Question:

How to directly... `collection.get('key1')//now returns undefined... because it is`.

I know i could expose an object to the global scope in the collection success function `some_other_var = data.toJSON()[0]` and access the `some_other_var` properties directly, but that's not what i'm looking for;

Comment: can you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the **get()** function from a **Backbone.Collection** you need to know the model id or cid wanted.

For instance, lets say your data coming from the server is like follow:

```
[{
id: '123',
name: 'Alex'
}, {
id: '456',
name: 'Jhon'
}]
```

In that case you can do this:

```
this.collection.get('123').get('name') // Return "Alex"
```

Keep in mind that collection is just a set of model, so behind the scenes by doing collection.get() you are getting a model

Tip: If you don't have any kind of id in your server data, there is always the option of using underscore methods:

- find
- filter
- some
- contains
- etc

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to ascribe attributes to a collection, but a collection is merely a set of models. Having additional data that is constant throughout the collection suggests that it should be wrapped inside another Model, which is demonstrated here: [Persisting & loading metadata in a backbone.js collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5932429)