# Making a model attribute "unique" among collection models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a collection of Backbone models, each having several attributes: _id, code, title, date and **selected**.

I want the "selected" attribute value to be **true** only in one of the collection models at a time. When I set a model "selected", all other models in the collection should be set to `{selected:false}`.

I'm thinking about two different solutions:

1) from "inside" the model: I can listen to the change of selected attribute, loop all the parent collection items, and set selected:false if _id != id of this

2) from "outside", loop over collection models, set all to selected:false, except the one who matches id I want to be selected:true.

Is there a better practice to do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a other solution 3)

Just as example, how to store additional data in collection. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930656/setting-attributes-on-a-collection-backbone-js)

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    meta: function(prop, value) {
        if (value === undefined) {
            return this._meta[prop]
        } else {
            this._meta[prop] = value;
        }
    },
});

var collection = new MyCollection();
collection.add(someModels);
collection.meta("selectedId", value);
```

You can store selectedId in collection meta propery. It will be always unique for each collection. 
And there is no need in 'selected' property in model.

Comment: You did not understand the question. Each model must have the selected property. I just want to avoid that more than one of them had it true at the same time!

Comment: then your 2 solutions should be used. without your attention attributes can change them self