# Giving a single reference to multiple Backbone.Models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone.Model which looks something like:

```
var FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        details: '',
        operatingSystem: ''
    };
});
```

There are many instances of FooModel which are stored in a collection:

```
var FooCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FooModel
});
```

FooModel's OperatingSystem is a property which only needs to be calculated once and is derived asynchronously. For example:

```
chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo(function(platformInfo){
    console.log("Operating System: ", platformInfo.os);
});
```

If I perform this logic at the FooModel level then I will need to perform the logic every time I instantiate a FooModel. So, I think that this operation should be performed at a higher level. However, it is [bad practice to give properties to a Backbone.Collection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930656/setting-attributes-on-a-collection-backbone-js)

As such, this leaves me thinking that I need a parent model:

```
var FooParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        platformInfo: '',
        fooCollection: new FooCollection()
    },

    initialize: function() {
        chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo(function(platformInfo){
            this.set('platformInfo', platformInfo);
        }.bind(this));
    },
    //  TODO: This will work incorrectly if ran before getPlatformInfo's callback
    createFoo: function(){
        this.get('fooCollection').create({
            details: 'hello, world',
            operatingSystem: this.get('platformDetails').os
        });
    }
});
```

This works and is semantically correct, but feels over-engineered. The extra layer of abstraction feels unwarranted.

Is this the appropriate way to go about giving a property to a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Backbone Collections may not have *attributes*, they may have *properties* (as well as any object) which you can use to store shared data.

```
var FooCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FooModel
    initialize: function() {
        this.platformInfo = null; // shared data
        chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo(function(platformInfo){
            this.platformInfo = platformInfo;
        }.bind(this));
    },
    // wrapper to create a new model within the collection
    createFoo: function(details) {
        this.create({
            details: details,
            operatingSystem: this.platformInfo? this.platformInfo.os : ''
        });
    }});
});
```

Comment: Of course a collection can have a property, but I get the impression that this is bad practice because Backbone doesn't provide 'defaults' for collections. Do you think this is true?

Comment: Why you need `defaults` in your case? `platformInfo` property get default value (`null`) in `initialize` method which is called from collection's constructor.